# Infinite Scroll + Masonry loading all items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, infinite-scroll, masonry

I'm trying to set up Masonry with Infinite Scroll, it works but it currently loads all items and then when I click on the next page link it loads them all again.

Nav:

```
<div class="more" id="navigation">
    <a href="./?page=2">MORE IDEAS</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

        (function() {

            // Main content container
            var $container = $('.grid');

            // Masonry + ImagesLoaded
            $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
                $container.masonry({
                    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
                    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
                    gutter: '.gutter-sizer',
                    percentPosition: true
                });
            });

            // Infinite Scroll
            $container.infinitescroll({

                // selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
                navSelector  : "#navigation",
                // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
                nextSelector : "#navigation a",
                // selector for all items you'll retrieve
                itemSelector : ".grid-item",

                },

                // Trigger Masonry as a callback
                function( newElements ) {
                    // hide new items while they are loading
                    var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
                    // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
                    $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
                        // show elems now they're ready
                        $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
                        $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
                    });

            });

            // Pause Infinite Scroll
            $(window).unbind('.infscr');

            // Resume Infinite Scroll
            $('.more a').click(function(){
                $container.infinitescroll('retrieve');
                return false;
            });

        })();

    });
```

Content:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
    <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>
    <div class="grid-item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Item 5</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Item 6</div>
</div>
```

Currently it loads all items, 1 to 6, then when I click the Load More button it loads items 1 to 6 again. I've looked on the couple of other questions which are similar to this but they are different circumstances. It's probably something simple, any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

You need to take part of the content you want loaded second out and put it in another html page. Then you need to set the navigation link to go to that page. As it was just set to ?page=2 it was just loading the same page again.